# js library to animate car's moving on a map in jpg format

Tags: html, animation, javascript

I have a map image in jpg format (not svg), and a sequence of (x,y) points which represents a car's moving location on the map.

I would like to create a html page to animate this car's moving on the map.

Could you recommend a js library that can easily achieve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

while i would do it with css3 to prevent an unnecesary http request, you can use this javascript library to use html5 canvas [kinetickJS](http://kineticjs.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need JavaScript to do this. Look into CSS animations. The exact CSS to produce this effect would be coupled to the HTML you're using to display the image and car.

If you have some HTML such as:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="car" src="/car.jpg" />
  <img src="/map.jpg" />
</div>
```

And some CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .car {
  position: absolute;
  top: #; // initial top offset
  left: #; // initial left offset
  animation: car-path 5s 0s 1 normal forwards; // shorthand
}

// define keyframes for the car animation.
// add as many intermediate states as you want.
// in each state simply define the position and 
// rotation of the car to simulate turning/acceleration
// change "0%" with the position you want the car in
@keyframes car-path {
  0% {
    top: 0%; 
    left: 0%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  // add as many intermediate positions as you want

  100% {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  } 
}
```

You can achieve some interesting results this way.